# Controlling Visibility on multiple ngFor elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

If you need to know more about the functionality that I will have, it is the following. I will have a project section with cards for each project that is populated from the JSON file. On the website when they click a card, there will be a hidden div that will be shown through a ngIf.

If you need a better example of what I am trying to accomplish, view this developer's website. I am trying to replicate the functionality he has in his project section: https://andrewborstein.com/

In the component, I import the JSON data and in the HTML section I use a ngFor to display each section like the example below:

Component File

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    for(var i = 0; i < ExperienceJSON["Experience"].length; i++)
        this.ExperienceList.push(ExperienceJSON["Experience"][i])
}
```

HTML File

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let Experience of ExperienceList">
    <mat-card>
    <div class="simple-content">{{Experience.sample}}</div>
    <div class="detailed-content" *ngIf="Visible">{{Experience.details}}</div>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Now, of course, I could assign a variable to each card and toggle visibility that way but that requires everything to be hardcoded in. I want to set it up in a way where me editing the JSON file is all that's needed. How would I be able to individually trigger the visibility of each card without hard-coding a variable for each?

I'm trying to wrap my head around the process but I have no idea how to really implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You either need to create an array of booleans, or add a property to each object (either to the JSON on your server, or you need to create it yourself in the component). I usually do the latter.

Comment: I don't really get your question. You could just do ngIf="Experience.IsVisible" or something.

Comment: @Silvermind So essentially the card will have an click function that when pressed will toggle the visibility of one of the child divs that belong to the card. I was trying to see if there was a method to implement this without giving each child div its own variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the conditional property on your json and put that in *ngIf for the template!

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let Experience of ExperienceList">
    <mat-card *ngIf='Experience.condtion'>
    <div class="simple-content">{{Experience.sample}}</div>
    <div class="detailed-content" *ngIf="Visible">{{Experience.details}}</div>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```